# Dynamic Slicer Selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this table that is feeding into a `PowerBI` report

```
select *
from 
    (
        values 
            (1,0),
            (2,0),
            (3,1),
            (4,0),
            (5,0),
            (6,0),
            (7,0),
            (8,0)
    ) as x(num, active)
```

Then in the report I have a slicer for `num`:

[image]

So - what I am trying to do is have 3 selected in the slicer - because it is marked 1 in the active column of the data BUT all other options in the num slicer should still be visible.

Then tomorrow if the data changes and 4 is marked 1 in the active column then it should be selected rather than 3

.... is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this is currently possible, but you can vote for a similar idea here:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7162004-default-selected-slicer-or-tile-by-value-configura

Comment: thanks - saves me chasing down something that is not possible